# Add Resume's property to the download manager written with Python and Requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, resume, download-manager, raw-data

I wrote a small script can get a link and download it.
Now I want to add `Resume`'s property to my script.
This script written in `python 3` and `requests` library.

Below is main download section of my code:

```
class downloader(Thread):
    def __init__(self,url,filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename=filename
        self.url=url
    def run(self):
        self.request()
    def request(self):
        headers = {'user-agent': 'pydownloader/0.0.1'}
        r=get(self.url,headers=headers,timeout=10,stream=True)
        with open(self.filename, 'wb') as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                fd.write(chunk)     
        _exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented that via Range  in http header

example:

Range:12343-   ===>  from 12343 to end

headers = {'user-agent': 'pydownloader/0.0.1','Range':'bytes=12343-'}